# Local and WCF design for a class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class which does stuffs with database, I want it to be used in these two ways:
1: a dll which can be referenced and used locally with direct call.
2: can be hosted as a WCF service.

when it is hosted as a WCF service many clients can connect to it but when it is used as a dll it just has one client.
how should I design my class?

For example I want to use it like this in dll form:

```
var a = new A();
```

and then call `a.DoSomething()`

or host it in WCF service and call `server.DoSomething()` from my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your class into an assembly of it's own along with any support classes it needs and just reference that assembly from your WCF service.

Put your "api" in an interface, implement it fully in your "work" assembly, then implement it in your WCF service, but just haave that act as a proxy. Using an interface will mean you don't miss anything in your proxy.

Comment: my answer still stands, you just wrap the class in a WCF service class, which just calls the "real work" class

Comment: I want different behavior for some functions when used as dll or over WCF.

Comment: you didn't say that in your question, regardless there is nothing to stop you from doing that as long as the DLL is a subset of what you want to do in your WCF in those cases where you want differences. But an interface just means you support that behaviour, you can do whatever you like internally.